# How to package react-native application

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-native

I am building a sample react native application. Currently i am running it using the node server.Node server is serving the js file.
You can see this in following screenshot:

[image]

I want to shift to the option2, for this, if there is any change in the js file, i need to run the curl command manually.

Is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's nothing in place and this is work in progress. See:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12

> We plan on putting in some sort of build step that "compiles" the JS
>   source directly into a resource file in the app bundle. Obviously in
>   production you wouldn't have a server running nearby.

There's another [bit of discussion here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/240).

At the moment I think you're stuck with the curl option.

Answer (score 0):

All  this does is packing all your JavaScript together and writing it into a single file. 
*Option 1* has a small http server running, providing the latest packed file when you request it.
*Option 2* takes the file from the local disk.

**You can setup a tool that looks watches your project files and repacks everything if you make changes.**

You can do this by yourself, using the packaging tool shipped with react-native (`react-native bundle [--minify]`) and re-run it everytime things changes using **[gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)** (and [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch)).

Also you can use **[webpack](http://webpack.github.io/)** as your packaging tool and use the *--watch*  option. (*[see example](https://github.com/roman01la/react-native-babel)*)